# Formatting text in into columns

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

It's been a long time since I've written a program in VB.NET, but now I'm trying to write a WinForm application.  I have several strings and I want to put them together so that they can added to a `ListView` control.

I have this:

```
text1 = ("00 | 34123 | 232")
text2 = ("023 | 233 | 23332 ")
text2 = ("00 | 2342432 | 122 ")
```

But I want this:

```
text1 = ("00     |     34123       |  232   ")
text2 = ("023    |     233         |  23332 ")
text2 = ("00     |     2342432     |  122   ")
```

Note that each number is a string variable, so that each number can be: "12" or "123" or "1234"... How I can do that!?

Comment: Couldn't you find the length of each string to know how many spaces to pad?  Or would inserting tab characters work for another solution here?

Comment: Just note that for listview (or textbox) you need a mono-spaced (Courier, Consola etc) font or they won't line up in either case (and you can remove the parenthesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function ToFixedColumns(ByVal input As String) As String
    'Separate individual items 
    Dim values = input.Split("|"c).Select(Function(s) s.Trim()).ToArray()

    'Validate split operation
    If values.Length <> 3 Then 
        Throw New InvalidArgumentException("The string was not in the correct starting format.")
    End If

    'Create new formatted string
    Return String.Format("{0,-6} |     {1,-12}  |  {2,-6}", _
           values(0),values(1),values(2))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) method.

Example usage:

```
Dim result = "00".PadRight(7) & "|    " _
             & "34123".PadRight(12) & "|  " _
             & "232".PadRight(6)
```

In this case, the `String.Format` approach is even better though. Note that for both approaches to work, you need to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: This only reliably works if you're using a monospaced font. If I were doing this project I would use a `DataGridView` or `ListView` with column right/left text-align settings set.

Comment: @Dai: You're right, the OP might be better served by using multiple columns instead. You could add an answer mentioning this.